# Misalignment of \vrule

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I have been writing my thesis and there is this one problem that I cant seem to figure out why it happens:

The following is a segment of the code from my thesis style sheet. This defines the first reader and second reader for my signature page.
And I have also attached a output snap of my PDF of the problem.
Can someone please tell me why this occurs?

```
% Signature page
\def\signaturepage{%
      \newpage
      \thispagestyle{empty} % KS 2009
      \begin{center}
        \Large\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}
      \end{center}
      \vspace{.4in}
      \centerline{\shortstack[c]{\vrule width 2in height 0.4pt\\
           \@author}}
      \vfill
%      \vspace{0.15in}
%      \hspace{0in} \rm APPROVED:
      \leftline{ Approved:} % KS 2009
      \vspace{0.15in}
      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt\\ \@adviser}}
 %     \vspace{0.15in}
       \vfill

      \leftline{Committee Members:} % KS 2009
 %    \vspace{0.375in}
     \vspace{0.15in}
      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt\\ \@firstreader}}
  %    \vspace{.375in}
      \vfill

      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt\\ \@secondreader}}
  %    \vspace{.375in}
      \vfill
```

This is what I get when I compile. the above code.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fixed `3in` rule width is good, but is also the problem here. Perhaps you can adjust your `\rightline` usage by using a fixed-width box (something like `tabular`). This way contents below the signature line will wrap as needed. I've defined `\signatureline` to be of width `.6\linewidth`, pushing its contents flush right as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\signatureline}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.6\linewidth}@{}}
    \hline \\[-.5\normalbaselineskip] #1
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent Approved:\par%
\vspace{0.15in}
\null \hfill \signatureline{Advisor\\A.\ B.\ Coverage\\Dept.\ of Electrical and Computer Engineering}
\vfill

\noindent Committee Members:\par%
\vspace{0.15in}
\noindent \hfill \signatureline{First Reader\\Dept.\ of Electrical and Computer Engineering}
\vfill

\noindent \hfill \signatureline{Second Reader\\Dept.\ of Physics}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

I've kept the other spacing as-is, although I would adjust them as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `\rightline` macro will shove its contents to the right of the page.  So your problem is not that the second reader's line is moved too far to the *right*, but that your *first* reader, and your committee chair, are pushed *left* a bit because their departmental affiliation lines are more than 3in long.  You can either modify the template so that the `\vrule width 3in` is replaced with a sufficiently wide `\vrule` (determined by trial and error) or you can insert a manual line break in the affiliation text, e.g. `Dept. of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering`.  Or use abbreviations, I suppose, depending on whether that is okay.

Answer (score 1):

At [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org) the problem has been solved in this topic: [Misalignment of \vrule](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22031).

The accepted solution contains two approaches:

- Recursive patching of `\signaturepage` to the desired depth to get a wider rule:

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \newcommand*{\patch}[1]{%
    \patchcmd{\signaturepage}{\vrule width 3in}{\vrule width 3.5in}{#1}{}}
  \patch{\patch{\patch{}}}
  ```
- Shortening entries or to introducing a line break for the wider texts, such as

  ```
  \firstreader{E. Joe Charlson, Professor\\ Dept. of Electrical and\\ Computer Engineering}
  ```